# How to add to state array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple to-do list app in React. I have 3 states, inputText (the task the user enters), triggerAnimation(to trigger animations), and tasks (the list of tasks user has entered). However I don't know how to update the tasks state (which is an array) to push the new tasks. Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputText: '',
      triggerAnimation: '',
      tasks: []
    }
  }

//The function triggered by button which sends the task the user has entered to the tasks array state:

  addItem() {
    document.querySelector("#textfield1").value = ""
    this.setState({ 
      triggerAnimation: 'fadein', tasks: 
      this.state.inputText 
    }) 
  }



  render() {
    //Where User enters task:
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <main>
          <div className="enterTask">
            <input type="text" className="inputclass" id="textfield1" 
              placeholder='Enter a task.' 
              onChange={event => this.setState({ 
                inputText: event.target.value })} 
              onKeyPress={event => {
                if(event.key === 'Enter') {
                  this.addItem();
                }
               }} 
             />
            <br />
            <br />
            <button className="button" 
              onClick={() => this.addItem()} data-
                toggle='fadein' data-target='list'>+
            </button>
         </div>


    <!-- Where tasks will appear: -->

         <div className="log">
           <p className='list'>
             <span class={this.state.triggerAnimation}>  
               {this.state.tasks}
             </span>
           </p>
           <button className="button">-</button>
         </div>
       </main>
     </div>
    )
  }
}  

export default App;
```

Comment: Please fix the formattig. Thats not readable at all

Comment: Your `addItem` method is resetting the state of tasks as a string. You can use the spread operator. `this.setState({tasks: [...this.state.task, this.state.inputText]})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like what you want is this..

```
addItem() {
document.querySelector("#textfield1").value = ""
this.setState({
            triggerAnimation: 'fadein',
            tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(this.state.inputText)}) 
}
```

Comment: How can I get the entire array to show in the html paragraph element?

Comment: <p>{this.state.tasks}</p> ?
or if you want each one in an individual paragraph tag
{this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => <p key={i}> {task} </p>} (in markup)

Comment: Hi Yes I'd like to get each in a individual tag, however I think your syntax is a little off because I'm getting an error at the ending bracket.  EDIT: I have fixed the problem, missing parentheses.

Comment: Never use `setState()` with input from `this.state`, as `this.state` may be outdated. Use the callback form when the state update depends previous state: `setState(prevState => ({ triggerAnimation: 'fadein', tasks: prevState.tasks.concat(prevState.inputText) }))`

Answer (score 9):

> However I don't know how to update the tasks state (which is an array) to push the new tasks.

Probably the cleanest way to "push to an array" in state is to use [ES6 array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The best practice would also be to use the [`setState` callback syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to ensure the correct state is committed before you push the new task:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  tasks: [...prevState.tasks, newTask] 
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.concat` method to create copy of your array with new data:

```
  addTask() {
    this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(["new value"])})
  }
```

You also need to bind `this` to `addTask` in your constructor:

`this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)`

See my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/103069/

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: `.concat` expects an Array as the argument. You should change it to: `this.state.tasks.concat(["new value"])`

Comment: I get the error  Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined  when adding this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this) to my constructor.

Comment: @Usman :) It's because `addTask` is not defined. You have a function called `addItem`. I used `addTask`. Try binding to the function that adds your items.

Answer (score 1):

FTFY better to just use comments in the code, regarding the problem(s) you want to get the tasks array then can concat the stuff to get a new array.

`setState({tasks:this.state.tasks.concat([this.state.inputText])})`

Wouldn't hurt to clean up the code some too... learning react myself the book "the road to learning react" has some good tips on how to set things up to be a bit more readable.

---

Edit actually put the right code here now...

Comment: @MarioTacke yes it does?  concat will create a new array attaching the elements from the original array to the array provided as an argument... not sure what is missing?

Comment: You should never mutate state directly. you are mutating the state value inside ref callback method to store the node ref.

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt .concat doesn't modify the original array it returns a new array... guess to be more complete I could add the setState part?

Comment: Not sure why everyone wants to hate this answer but you're the third to come by and down vote or leave a review mark on this without giving a clear reason why...

Comment: @shaunhausin While it is technically possible to alter state by writing to this.state directly, it will not lead to the Component re-rendering with new data, and generally lead to state inconsistency. The fact that setState causes reconciliation(the process of re-rendering the components tree) is base of the next property — setState is asynchronous. This allows us to have multiple calls to setState in a single scope and not trigger not needed re-renders of the whole tree.

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt right I understand that what I'm saying is concat doesn't modify the original array no mutation occurs here... I'll add the setState call for clarification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Please read: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

@shaunhusain

Comment: What does that have to do with what's in my answer?

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt also from what I understand setState can run synchronously or asynchronously but should be treated as async, using either the function as a first param or callback to handle anything that needs to happen after the state actually changes... still I wasn't mutating anything in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import React from 'react';

class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      items: []
    }
  }

  onChange = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })

  onEnter = e => {
    if(e.charCode !== 13) return;
    this.addItem();
  };

  onClick = e => {
    this.addItem()
  };

  addItem = () => {
    const { value } = this.state;
    if(!!value.trim()) return;
    this.setState(prev => ({ items: [...prev.items, value], value: '' }))
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={value}
            name="abc"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With react, you're almost always going to have to store form field information in state (controlled components) so, how about turning todo task input field into a controlled component, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            inputText: '',
            triggerAnimation: '',
            tasks: []
        }

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onInputKeyPress = this.onInputKeyPress.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    onInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({ inputText: e.target.value });
    }

    onInputKeyPress(e) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            this.addItem();
        }
    }

    addItem() {
        const itemToAdd = this.state.inputText;
        const tasks = this.state.tasks;
        this.setState({
            inputText: "",
            tasks: tasks.concat(itemToAdd);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { inputText } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" className="inputclass" id="textfield1" placeholder='Enter a task.' 
                   value={inputText} onChange={this.onInputChange} onKeyPress={this.onInputKeyPress} />
                <br />
                <br />
                <button className="button" onClick={this.addItem} data-
                toggle='fadein' data-target='list'>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Notice how input state is controlled via component state