# How to set data in react typescript array of object from axios response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am using react with typescript I am trying to fetch the data from the API using Axios. I created a state of an array of objects and tried to set the data from the response in Axios then:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<Users[]>([]);

type Users = {
    userId: number,
    name: string,
}

useEffect(() => {

const response = async () => {
        await axios.get(
          "https://localhost:5000/users",{
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        );
      }

 response().then((res) => {
        setUsers({userId: res.userId, name: res.name})
      })


},[])
```

I am getting on `setUsers` saying: Argument of type '{ userId: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Users[]>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userId' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<Users[]>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add to state array in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795792/how-to-add-to-state-array-in-react)

Comment: this question not related with typescript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it to the last state:

```
response().then((res) => {
    setUsers((prevUsers) => prevUsers.concat(res));
    // setUsers((prevUsers) => [...prevUsers, res]); // another way
});
```

TypeScript is complaining because you are giving `users` a single `Users` object and not an array.

Comment: still complaining: ```Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Users'```